# Loading fade animation not shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Animations</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function({
   
      $("Header").fadeIn(1000);
  
      });
    </script>
    <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans+Condensed');
    *{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }
    #Container{
    width: 1368px;
    }
    #Header{
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #00f;
    }
    h1{
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 200px;
      font-size: 55px;
      font-family: 'Fira Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
      color: #fff;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
 <div id="Container">
  <div id="Header">
  <h1 id="h1">Welcome to Website</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The problem is in displaying it statically when the page loads, it is not fading as defined in the **jQuery** code. Can the problem be associated with the rendering of the **HTML**?

Comment: Did you try querying by id and not tag?  $('#Header')

Comment: You have to select the header with a `#` wich stands for selecting an Id. Like `$("#header").fadeIn(1000);`. Plus you should put your script before the closing `</body>` tag

Comment: yes there is a mistake i have written #Header still the code is not working

Comment: @CodingGeeks you have to notice person who give the first correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you want to fadeIn some element its previous state should be display:none;
Update that and it will work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Animations</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#Header").fadeIn(1000);

});
</script>
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans+Condensed');
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
#Container{
width:1368px;
}
#Header{
height:200px;
background-color:blue;
display: none;
}
h1{
text-align:center;
line-height:200px;
font-size:55px;
font-family: 'Fira Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
color:white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Container">
    <div id="Header">
    <h1 id="h1">Welcome to Website</h1>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Same answer as me. Why you copied from other?

Comment: @CodingGeeks I have given answer first.

Comment: @BharatsingParmar I did't copied you buddy. Its just that you have answered it while I was answering it.

Comment: @BharatsingParmar He didn't necessarily copy you. Your answers were ~1 minute apart. It probably took him longer to write the answer, than a minute, hence why he probably did not copy you + this really is the most basic thing to do in jQuery, thus increasing the likelihood of him probably knowing the answer.

Comment: @the12 I know this is basic thing. So person need to give answer fast.

Comment: Wooo dude seriously ... you just down voted the question just because he didn't accepted you answer.. so mean .. @CodingGeeks can you please mark BharatsingParmar 's answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function({

$("Header").fadeIn(1000);

})
```

with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Header").fadeIn(1000);
})
```

Comment: still the problem is there

Answer (score 0):

Try this updated working code: [jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/23eq98qy/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/23eq98qy/1/)

To take fadeIn effect need to add `display:none` style in div

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Header").fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Comment: bharat typing mistake was there i originally typed this the problem is there

Answer (score 0):

To apply fadeIn effect you must have to hide dive uding display:none 
change

```
<div id="Header">
```

to

```
<div id="Header" style="display: none;">

<script>
$(document).ready(function({

$("#Header").fadeIn(1000);

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Coding Geeks Try this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {$("#Header").fadeIn(1000); } );
</script>
```

instead of

```
<script> 
   $(document).ready(function({ $("Header").fadeIn(1000); });
</script>
```